# AndroidStudio method's color become green

Tags: android-studio

I  don't know what happened ?

My Android Studio method color is  green , that is terrible ! 
Look  my  picture !  I want  the  color  become  normal !
Please anybody help me?

[image]

Comment: I think restart android studio will help, or restart PC.

Comment: @EricWong Thank you !   restart  has  solved the  problem